# Large Deviation Principle for multivariat Gaussian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution, large-deviation-theory

Let us consider the law $\mu_{\epsilon}$ of a multivariat normally distributed random vector X~$\mathcal{N}(0, \epsilon I)$ with mean vector [0,...,0] and covariance Matrix equal to the identity matrix times $\epsilon>0$.
Does the Family $\left\{\mu_{\epsilon}:\epsilon>0\right\}$ satisfy a Large Deviation Principle?
I know it should be the case for the univariate normal Distribution where one can Show this via Cramers Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This is an easy consequence of (say) the [.Gärtner-Ellis Theorem](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/754/2006/notes/lecture-34.pdf).  In your case the relevant cumulant generating function is easy to work out.